# Dynamics CRM and Outlook how auto track emails

Tags: email, outlook, synchronization, dynamics-crm, server-side-sync

My task is make auto tracking emails from Outlook to CRM.
Now user can track emails only manually, when going to the message and click Dynamics->Track, but I need to do it automatically, and outgoing mail must tracked in CRM when user send it from Outlook (users don't want to send emails from CRM, they are all using only Outlook Web, Outlook desktop client and Outlook for Mac).

I find an answer is to make folders and auto track that folders, but the limit of this folders is 25 and this is too few for us.

Maybe some one know the desigion of auto tracking emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue as i see it is that CRM has no knowledge of an email sent from the outlook web mail client to an external address, and therefore cannot track it.

I think you can accomplish what you need using some Exchange gymnastics (I'm more of a CRM than an Exchange guy but believe the following should work).

1. Create the following new mailboxes: ***auto-tracked@acme.com***; ***auto-tracked-preprocess@acme.com***;
2. Create a new Queue in CRM: *auto-tracked@acme.com*
3. Create an exchange rule to forward all outgoing emails to the *auto-tracked-preprocess@acme.com* mailbox.
   (http://www.oxfordsbsguy.com/2013/03/09/how-to-copy-incoming-or-outgoing-emails-to-another-mailbox-in-exchange-2007-or-2010/)
4. Create an additional rule to process the emails hitting the *auto-tracked-preprocess@acme.com* mailbox to do the following:
   (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919237(v=exchg.150).aspx)

   - Add *auto-tracked@acme.com* as a cc recipients to the email
   - Redirect the email to crm-tracked@acme.com
5. Configure the Email Router or Server Side Sync to track all emails send to *auto-tracked@acme.com*

Unfortunately you cannot just bcc the emails to the auto-tracked mailbox as CRM requires that someone on the *to* or *cc* list be a CRM User or Queue.

The solution is to cause the emails you wish tracked to be cc'd to a tracked mailbox.  The email should then be tracked in CRM with the correct senders and recipients. The caveat is that you will have crm-tracked@acme.com as a reciepient on all of these emails.